# useRef audio reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Intento extraer la duración del audio pero me lo devuelve como Infinity pero en cambio el currentTime si me da correctamente el valor

```
const audio = useRef();
const [url, setUrl] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
        setUrl("http://localhost:4000/beats/audio/" + beatSeleccionado.beat);
    }, [beatSeleccionado]);

useEffect(() => {
        if (beatSeleccionado._id) {
            console.log(audio.current.duration); // Retorna al inicio NaN y luego Infinity
            console.log(audio.current.currentTime); //Retorna correctamente
        }
    })

<audio ref={audio} src={url} autoPlay />
```

El beat viene desde un context

```
    const { beatSeleccionado } = useContext(BeatContext);
```

Comment: El primer retorno `NaN` es el del primer render, no hay video, eso parece ser normal. En el siguiente render, el video que estas cargando en audio puede no tiene duración predefinida [Audio tag tech details](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp)

Comment: cómo haría en ese caso? porque tengo un reproductor custom y quería agregar un progress bar

Comment: Yo intentaría hacer algo con la propiedad [buffered](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_buffered.asp) saludos